# Peak, in a hurry

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, rebus

### What's the two-word (13 letters) phrase I'm looking for?

---

[image]

Hint 1:

> Why the rectangular shape? What can they possibly represent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may clue

> Mount Rushmore

As this depicted in the image has the

> US presidents  George Washington, Thomas Jefferson, Theodore Roosevelt and Abraham Lincoln sculpted on it and
>  the US dollar notes for 1 = George Washington, 2 = Thomas Jefferson, none for Theodore Roosevelt and 5 =Abraham Lincoln

The title Peak, in a hurry describes

> Mount Rush more :)

Comment: This is it! Well done.